# groupby and selecting in pandas

Tags: select, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to remove some rows in my table based on the change column.

```
id  subindex    change
A1      1           0
A1      2           1
A1      3           12
A1      4           0
A1      5           15
A1      6           1
A2      1           0
A2      2           11
A2      3           1
A2      4           0
```

In a subgroup (Id is identical) When change is higher than 10, I want to remove the subsequent rows. So the table would be:

```
 id subindex    change
A1      1           0
A1      2           1
A2      1           0
```

What I did is a groupby to identify where the sub-tables should be cut:

```
df['cut_position']=df[df.change >= 10].groupby('id')['subindex'].transform(lambda x: x.min())
```

that gives:

```
id  subindex    change      cut_position
A1      1           0           0
A1      2           1           0
A1      3           12          3
A1      4           0           0
A1      5           15          0
A1      6           1           0   
A2      1           0           0
A2      2           11          2
A2      3           1           0
A2      4           0           0
```

Then a groupby('id') should be easy to do, but I get problems trying to obtain that table:

```
id  subindex    change      cut_position
A1      1           0           0
A1      2           1           0
A1      3           12          ToRemove_3
A1      4           0           ToRemove_0
A1      5           15          ToRemove_0
A1      6           1           ToRemove_0  
A2      1           0           0
A2      2           11          ToRemove_2
A2      3           1           ToRemove_0
A2      4           0           ToRemove_0
```

When writing the code that could generate the table, I get :

```
df.groupby('id')[df['subindex'] >= df['cut_position'].max()].map(lambda x : 'ToRemove_' + x)
```

*KeyError: 'Columns not found: False, True'*

Note: I did something that worked, but it took way too much time to do it...

Comment: A change of 10 means the quality of the data has weakened from this point and below. So I want to remove all data below the one that had a change of 10 or more.

Comment: Thx Sara.  I removed my comment after reviewing your question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% satisfied with this approach, but you could try it.

Given your frame

```
id  subindex    change
A1      1           0
A1      2           1
A1      3           12
A1      4           0
A1      5           15
A1      6           1
A2      1           0
A2      2           11
A2      3           1
A2      4           0
```

Then create a frame with the first row of each 'id' thats greater than 10

```
rowindex = df['change'] > 10
greaterThan10 = df[rowindex].groupby('id',as_index=False).first()
```

Than a merge() of your original frame and greaterThan10

```
dfKeep = pd.merge(df,greaterThan10,how='left',on=['id'],suffixes=['','_cut'])
```

Then filtering the new frame for the 'keepers'

```
mask = (dfKeep['subindex'] < dfKeep['subindex_cut']) 
dfKeep[mask][['id','subindex','change']]
```

gives you

```
    id  subindex    change
0   A1  1           0
1   A1  2           1
6   A2  1           0
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, that does it and it is quite fast.

Comment: Good deal.  Thanks for the feedback